# Cant publish lightswitch application after VS2013 Migration

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I recently upgraded my Lightswitch Project to VS2013 from VS2012. I tried publishing the project and got this error

```
Error 3  The "ResolvePublishParameters" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Publish.Tasks.Deployment.ResolvePublishParameters.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.LightSwitch.Publish.Tasks.Common.BuildTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v4.0\Publish\v2.2\Microsoft.LightSwitch.Publish.targets
411 10
```

Clues on how to fix this? I cant even publish a local package

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, it took a while but look in your downloads and there might be an Azure software installed. You don't need it it just updates something you don't need and screws up your compiler. Look for it, I'm not sure about the name exactly but it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me was:

1. Start the LightSwitch Publish Application Wizard.
2. Go to the Data Connections step.
3. Switch to the Attached Data Sources tab.
4. If there are any Connections there, set their values to be **completely blank.**

This is counter-intuitive -- seems like you'd want the correct value for your Attached Data Sources there -- but blanking these out made the errors go away, as it also did for [Ian Mac, here](http://msdn.developer-works.com/article/11307354/Cant+publish+lightswitch+application+after+VS2013+Migration+).